# Can we ask the view of both Shia & Sunni in a question? (If we recognize it won't make a bad argument...)

Tags: discussion, shia-sunni, asking-questions

Occasionally we can recognize that the answer of a question (from the view of both Shia and Sunni) will relatively be pretty the same, but we want to see the precise answer of them, then, can we inquire such questions and ask the view of Sunni and Shia in a question if we assume that it won't make a bad argument between them?

(Since I reckon it could even increase the attractiveness of site (for the users to see a nice argument...)

Comment: 1. Add examples to your question to make it easier to understand what is the issue. 2. Why not ask it separately? Does asking for both in the same question solve any problem? 3. How can you know the answers will be similar if you don't know the answer from them? 4. If you are sure that the answer will be similar, why ask for both? Just ask for one and by your assumption the answer from the other is similar.

Comment: The current accepted answer flies in the face of the SE model. Please give goldPseudo's answer another look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Of course. There is no problem in knowing other people's beliefs.

> O mankind! We created you from a single (pair) of a male and a female, and made you into nations and tribes, that ye may know each other (not that ye may despise (each other). Verily the most honoured of you in the sight of Allah is (he who is) the most righteous of you. And Allah has full knowledge and is well acquainted (with all things). (Qur'an 49:13)

It may be possible that sometimes Sunnis are wrong or sometimes Shias are wrong.

Debating shouldn't be the motive but to know the views is fine by asking view specific questions, by that there won't be any disagreement. The rest please refer to goldPseudo's answer.

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: The aim of the question nor the answer should be to prove any sect "right" or "wrong".

Comment: wrong in the sense, as some aspects of Sunnis might be wrong or some aspects of Shias might be wrong, there is no way to prove that either of the two are entirely wrong. @BleedingFingers

Comment: We are [not a site for debate](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22).  The whole point of the Stack Exchange model is to cut through all the noise that you already get on forums etc (i.e. the debating) and just give the actual *answers*.

Comment: Well my point is not debating and trying to prove one is better than other. But, we just listen to them what they feel, we just tell them what we feel, and say good bye to each other. That's it.

Comment: @servantofWiser Yes, but that should be done in _separate_ questions, not in the same one.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with all this talk about “objective answers” is that there is actually very little about which all Muslims are in agreement. Yes, we all accept the Qur’an and we all pray in the direction of the Ka’bah. But on everything else: tafsīr al-Qur’an, which aḥādīth (if any) are “authentic”, uṣūl al-fiqh, kalām, etc., there is no universal agreement, not only between Sunnah and Shi’ah, but also between the Sunni madhāhib or the different schools of kalām, to say nothing of “modernist” movements like the salafiyyah. An “objective” answer is one that recognises the diversity of Muslim positions. And perhaps even considers the possibility that the answer might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason why not.  What's important is that it's asked in such a way that it attracts answers that actually and completely *answer the question*.

In my experience, most of the questions which do ask for answers according to both Sunni and Shi'ite perspectives only attract *items* rather than *answers*; you'll get one post which explains <strike>the</strike> a Sunni perspective, and another post which explains <strike>the</strike> a Shi'ite perspective, and these just get voted on based on popularity; this is pretty much *exactly not* how the Stack Exchange model is intended to work.

If your question is asked in such a way as to only attract these sorts of *items*, that's the definition of "opinion-based" and should be closed as such.  If the question is not so-phrased, but still attracting such items instead of actual *answers*, those need to be *explicitly discouraged*, i.e. by downvoting, deleting and/or flagging as NAA (otherwise, again, the question itself will likely need to be closed as opinion-bait).

Is it possible to actually *ask* such a question constructively?  I'm sure it is, but the onus is still on (a) the questioner and (b) the community to *make* it work.